# PowerShell run bat from location on my computer on remote computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to run a BAT file on some servers
Because of the amount of many servers I avoid copying the file on any server

I have the file on my computer and I try to access it remotely

```
$CMDCOMMAND = "\\Mycomp\c$\file.bat"    
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Hostname -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process cmd.exe "/c $CMDCOMMAND
}
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Computer $Hostname -Credential $Cred -FilePath $CMDCOMMAND`?

Comment: no, not work :(

Comment: You will need to provide a little more information than that. We're not the ones sitting in front of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $Hostname -Credential $Cred -FilePath $CMDCOMMAND
```

should work as @Ansgar Wiechers mentioned.

I doubt you have set `$CMDCOMMAND = "\\Mycomp\c$\file.bat"` and tried. It should be local path when you pass it to `-FilePath`

```
$CMDCOMMAND = "c:\file.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Command does not work with a variable defined outside the ScriptBlock. You need to use the ArgumentList parameter. Something like this should work, although I have not tested it:

```
$CMDCOMMAND = "\\Mycomp\c$\file.bat"    
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Hostname -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
param($ARGLIST) Start-Process cmd.exe "/c $ARGLIST" 
} -ArgumentList $CMDCOMMAND
```